# Replace only the Second number from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, multi-index

How do i replace the second number from a string only?

Actual sting:
`messages_0_items_0_data_0`

Required Results:
`messages_0_items_1_data_0`

```
var new_index = 1;
this_input.attr('id', this_input.attr('id').replace(/[0-9]+(?!.*[0-9])/, new_index ));
```

the above code is changing the last number rather than the second number like follwoing:

Not Good:
`messages_0_items_0_data_1`

Comment: If the "strings" are always formatted like that, then you can `.split()` by the underscore, and make whatever adjustments.

Comment: @GetSet No, the strings are sometimes `messages_0_items_0_data_0` and sometimes `messages[0][items][0][data][0]`

Comment: Then you should mention that in your question. Mention in your question actual input test cases, and desired output.

Comment: Unless you are sure, your 2nd use case of `messages[0][items][0][data][0]` as a string doesn't jibe well on a string being formatted as such. Perhaps you included this in comments to show how you want to access the data in code form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture just before the second number in group 1, and then match the second number to be replaced.

```
^(\D*\d+\D+)\d+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QEIgm5/1).

```js
const s = `messages_0_items_0_data_0
messages[0][items][0][data][0]`;
const regex = /^(\D*\d+\D+)\d+/gm;
console.log(s.replace(regex, (m, g1) => `${g1}1`));
```